# cypher indexing common property on all nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

As per new indexing rules, the `auto_index` will go away in future and its expected to create indexes using `cypher`. According to this new way, to index a node property, you MUST provide a Node Label.

**I have a 'nodeId' property present on all types of Node Labels - User, Employee, Bank, Car, etc.** I used to auto-index this property to retrieve any type of node if its nodeId is known. Please note that since auto-index did not require me to give a Node Label, it was possible for me to do what I did.

```
ReadableIndex<Node> readableIndex = this.graphDatabaseService.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
readableIndex.get("nodeId", "0").getSingle();
```

But with new style, I have to create index on nodeId property for each and every Node Label. So I have to do this:

```
create index on :User(nodeId)
create index on :Employee(nodeId)
...
```

Moreover, my method `getByNodeId(String nodeId)` is useless now because this cypher query IMHO will not be able to use the index anymore since I am not passing any node label.

```
match (node) where node.nodeId = {nodeId} return node;
```

Since the whole point of my `getByNodeId()` method was to be generic across all nodes, I cannot give this cypher query a node label. So what should I do here. My 2 questions are:

- How do I tell neo4j via cypher to index on all node labels
- How do I write a cypher query which uses index not based on node label, but based on node property.

**Note:**

- It is essential for me to use cypher because I am using neo4j-jdbc
  and they have no method to create auto-index or access the
  auto-indexer (atleast not that I know of).
- Some might suggest me to change the neo4j.properties to enable
  auto-indexing there, but I dont like changing configuration files. I
  want to do it in my program. Anyway, that would have only solved the
  first issue. Second issue is still there.

Comment: Thanks for asking this! I was about to ask the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node can have multiple labels.

Thus, if you make all your nodes share a common label, say `Base` (in addition to whatever labels they currently have), you can just have a single index that covers all your nodes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Base(nodeId)
```

Comment: This is definitely a good answer. However is there really no other way? Here is why - I have three different database flavors - neo4j embedded and rest, and titan. I want all of them to have the same graph structure because it helps me keep stuff simple. I would not like to deviate from the consistency of 3 databases until I really really have to. Though your answer makes a lot of sense, having more than one label is something Titan does not support. Hence I would only use it if there is no other way. Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: You can omit the shared label in the non-neo4j DBs. Aside from that, the structure should be the same.

Comment: Thank you! A bit of unnecessary work having to create a label on ALL nodes (any way to make it automatic?), but it gets the job done.